# How to repeat a ctrl+ keybinding in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently switched from MacVim to VS Code, and am setting up some keybindings to simulate what I enjoyed in mvim. Currently, I have a key binding set up to switch between open editor windows:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
}
```

This works as expected for a one-time press: if I press `ctrl+h`, it shows the previous active editor in the group and will select it once I release the key. What I'd like to be able to do is continue to hold the `ctrl` key and keep pressing `h` to cycle through all open editors. This works for the original mapping of this command (`ctrl+tab`), but not with the remap.

Anyone know how to get this to be a repeatable keybinding? Also, is there a term for this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two keybindings for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> in `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key":     "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup"
}
```

and

```
{
  "key":     "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker",
  "when":    "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen"
}
```

Did you copy both of those for your new binding?

Comment: Ahh that explains it! No, I did not have the second key binding copied. Thanks.